# Making zsh filename completion case-insensitive everywhere

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, git

I have the following line in my zshrc to make filename completions case-insensitive:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}'
```

This works most of the time but I’ve noticed that if I type “git add ” and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> then the completions I get are case-sensitive.

Is there a different command I should be using to make filename completions case-insensitive? Or do I need to start adding `zstyle` declarations for individual commands? (And if that’s the answer, what should those declarations look like?)

### Configuration

I was able to reproduce the behavior I described above with macOS 12.4, Zsh 5.8.1, the following zshenv file:

```
setopt NO_GLOBAL_RCS
```

and the following zshrc file:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}'
zstyle ':completion:*' cache-path /var/tmp/zcompcache
autoload -U compinit && compinit -d /var/tmp/zcompdump
```